# Implementation of priority queue by AVL Tree data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Priority queue:
          Basic operations: Insertion
                      Delete (Delete minumum element)

Goal: To provide efficient running time or order of growth for above functionality.

**Implementation of Priority queue By:**

```
Linked List: Insertion will take o(n) in case of insertion at end o(1) in case of 
             insertion at head.
             Delet (Finding minumum and Delete this ) will take o(n) 

BST:
   Insertion/Deltion of minimum = In avg case it will take o(logn) worst case 0(n)

AVL Tree: 
   Insertion/deletion/searching: o(log n) in all cases.
```

***My confusion goes here:***

Why not we have used AVL Tree for implementation of Priority queue, Why we gone 
   for Binary heap...While as we know that in AVL Tree we can do  insertion/ Deletion/searching in o(log n) in worst case.

Comment: @UmNyobe: In terms of order of grwoth it is same. but in terms of speed it is different....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complexity isn't everything, there are other considerations for actual performance.

For most purposes, most people don't even use an AVL tree as a balanced tree (Red-Black trees are more common as far as I've seen), let alone as a priority queue.

This is not to say that AVL trees are useless, I quite like them. But they do have a relatively expensive insert. What AVL trees are good for (beating even Red-Black trees) is doing lots and lots of lookups without modification. This is not what you need for a priority queue.

As a separate consideration -- never mind your O(log n) insert for a binary heap, a fibonacci heap has O(1) insert and O(log N) delete-minimum. There are a lot of data structures to choose from with slightly different trade-offs, so you wouldn't expect to see everyone just pick the first thing that satisfies your (quite brief) criteria.

Comment: I appriciate your answer steve and say thanks to you, but as far as my question is concerned I just wan't to know why We move for binary heap...I know behind every theorem/invention some point is hidden here just I wanted to know in terms of time complexity....I think time complexity is one of the major factor for deciding and choosing data structure

Comment: @Nishant: you are not going to find the answer solely in terms of complexity, since as you have noticed the complexities for an AVL tree and a binary heap are the same. People choose a binary heap when it's faster than an AVL tree (or perhaps smaller). Complexity != speed.

Comment: Your comment given answer of my questions...Very very thanks.Have a great day steve and willness you to many many thanks..

Comment: Also, a binary heap can be implemented using an arrary[] instead of node/pointers which makes most operations much quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Binary heap is not Binary Search Tree (BST). If severely unbalanced / deteriorated into a list, it will indeed take O(n) time. Heaps are usually always O(log(n)) or better. IIRC Sedgewick claimed O(1) average-time for array-based heaps.

Why not AVL? Because it maintains ***too much order*** in a structure. Too much order means, too much effort went into maintaining that order. The less order we can get away with, the better - it will usually translate to ***faster operations***. For example, RBTs are better than AVL trees. RBTs, red-black trees, are *almost* balanced trees - they save operations while still ensuring O(log(n)) time.

But any tree is totally-ordered structure, so heaps are generally better, because they only ensure that the minimal element is on top. They are only partially ordered.

Comment: +1, "maintain too much order" is a good way to express why a tree is overkill.

Comment: @SteveJessop there's a book by Feynman I think, where he took CS on in terms of entropy and such. Though I still haven't read it. )

Comment: @Will and Steve: In binary heap we have to also maintain structure property and a heap order property as we maintain in AVL for balance

Comment: @Nishant there is less order in heap than in tree. If you do an in-order traversal of a tree you get an ordered list. But if you do a pre-order traversal of a heap, you don't get an ordered list. In heap, left and right branches can be freely exchanged. Not so in trees.

Comment: @WillNess: For Maintaion order in heap Time complexity is O(log n). Willness I think in terms of complexity we can't compare between AVL and Binary heap..We have to take Speed in account..I thing reason for using Binary heap is speed of algorithm not coplexity...For Instance in terms of order of growth 1000log(n) is still log(n)  is same but in case of speed both are different..Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: @Nishant you got it. That's exactly what Steve was saying to you. Of two algos with same complexity, one will be faster, and the other slower. And usually the one that has to spare too much effort while maintaining too much order in its data, will be slower.

Answer (score 2):

Because in a binary heap the minimum element is the root.

Comment: there's more than just `peek` to priority queues. There's also `pop`, `insert`, and sometimes `popAndReinsert`.

Comment: I didn't mention peek. By definition binary heap a node is `smaller` than its children. Just this property should raise an alarm.